# Java: nested method local inner classes and accessibility

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I've been trying out various scoping tricks using nested classes and found one particular case I'm stumped on.

Assume you have doubly nested local classes as so:

```
public class Outer {
    private final String className = "outer";

    public Outer() {}

    public void doThings() {
        class Inner {
            private final String className = "inner";
            public Inner() {}
            public void doThings() {
                class InnerInner {
                    private final String className = "inner-inner";
                    public InnerInner() {}
                    public void doThings() {
                        System.out.println("Outer class: "+Outer.this.className);
                        // How to access the Inner member?
                        System.out.println("InnerInner class: "+this.className);
                    }
                }

                InnerInner ii = new InnerInner();
                ii.doThings();
            }
        }

        Inner i = new Inner();
        i.doThings();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        o.doThings();
    }
}
```

As near as I can tell, class Inner is out of scope of the InnerInner class.  Is there anyway that InnerInner can see its calling instance of Inner?  Of course, using `Outer.Inner.this.className` would fail because Inner is not visible through Outer.

As an aside, I do realize this is a highly unconventional and improper java idiom but one that I believe is interesting especially to highlight the difference between scope chaining in prototypal languages like javascript and OO languages like java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following -

```
System.out.println("Inner class: " + Inner.this.className);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
 System.out.println("Inner class: " + Inner.this.className);
```